# Magento2: Translate knockout variable with odd beahaivor

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, knockoutjs, i18n

I want to translate a variable in Knockout

```
<span id="sales_unit" data-bind="i18n:sales_unit"></span>
```

sales_unit has the value pair. The value should be translated to a different language

---

Actual Result:

```
<span id="sales_unit" data-bind="i18n:sales_unit">pair</span>
```

Target Result:

```
<span id="sales_unit" data-bind="i18n:sales_unit">pár</span>
```

---

It only will translate correctly, if i add the result string in knockout once

```
<span id="sales_unit_pair" data-bind="i18n:'pair'" style="display:none"></span>
```

If I delete this line afterwards, the translation magicaly works from now on, until i clear the cache.

This is not really a pretty solution and is only a workaround. Does anybody know, how i can fix this?

Comment: Hello ! I'm having exactly the same issue, did you find any solution? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Did you re-deploy everything by locale/language too?

You need to add the CSV file with your translations in the language folder i18n inside your theme. Here are the details explained better: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Try to not override directly the Ko templates values, that could make strange behavior in some cases.